# background problem in unity for open world 2d game

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, background

[image: image screen shot]

my player could walk freely in x and y-axis, at the first I used this code to bring the player back into the background when it crossed the borders from other side but then I had to make lots of new calculation for other objects in the scene like Coins and Enemies to correct their positions

```
    private void MapControl()
    {
        if (transform.position.y > MapSize)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, 0);
        }
        else if (transform.position.y < 0)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, MapSize);
        }
        else  if (transform.position.x > MapSize)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(0, transform.position.y);
        }
        else if (transform.position.x < 0)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(MapSize, transform.position.y);
        }
    }
```

I want to know which one is better? duplicate my background to where my player goes (x and y axis) and how? or keep the player inside the main background using the above code?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Are you trying to reduce the calculations you have to make?

Comment: @SonicBlue22 i want to know which one is better ? duplicate my background to where my player goes and how? or keep the player inside the main background?

Comment: i put the question at the end please reopen thanks

Comment: If you want someone to help you, we need to know more specifically what you want. Did you try PrinceOfRaven's answer? Why didn't it work?

Answer (score 1):

click on the `camera`. in the inspector you can set it to an image background, and set the image, it will stay in view permanently.

alternatively, you could add the background as a sprite image, scale it to fit you camera view, and then make it a child of the camera. it is important to note that if you decide to do this, be sure to move the `background` into the background. i.e. adjust its `z` (depth)

both of these solutions will work, and give you a static background(it will remain still in the background no matter what)

if however you wish to have the background move as your player crosses it, you will need to tile the texture, there are several tutorials for programming a `tileable` background.

something like(pseudo):

```
int tileswide=10;
int tileswide=10;
float tilewidth=Screen.width;
float tileheight=Screen.height;


for(int x =0; x<tileswide;x++){

   for(int y =0; y<tileswide;y++){

       instantiate(object);
       Vector3 pos = new Vector3(x*tilewidth,y*tileheight,3);
       object.transform.position=pos;

   }

}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply , is it working on two axis? my player runs on x and y freely . i could not find a proper code so far (my player moves on world not background)